# Reading a one-dimensional data series spread over columns with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, file, numpy, io

In my field a lot of data files are formatted like this:

```
1.0  0.4  -0.3  0.2  1.0
2.2 -0.3   3.2  2.2  1.2
0.5  0.3   0.3 -4.4  1.2
0.2  1.2  -0.6
```

Where the data series represented is just a one-dimensional array of numbers (they've just been arbitrarily grouped into 5 columns per row, except for the last row).

I can read this with the following hack

```
txtdata = open('data.dat').read().replace('\n', ' ')
data = np.fromstring(txtdata, sep=' ')
```

But surely there's a better way? One that doesn't involve iterating over the data twice? `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` don't seem to support this.

Comment: In your "hack", there is no need to replace the newlines with spaces.  As the docstring for `fromstring` explains, when `sep` is not an empty string,  "extra whitespace is also ignored", and a newline is whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have extraneous whitespaces :

```
with open('file') as f:
    array = []
    for line in f:
        array.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])
```

You can condense the loop into a nested list comprehension:

```
with open('file') as f:
    array = [[float(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f]
```

Comment: Yep, I could do this (using `float` instead of `int`), but as I understand it, converting from a `list` to a NumPy `ndarray` afterwards involves a second traversal of the data.

Comment: You just need to put : `numpyArray = numpy.asarray(array, dtype=None, order=None)`